# How to Get the value of a datatype from Class of Project2 to Class of Project1? - Visual Studio 2010 C#

Tags: c#, instance

I have 1 solution consisting of 2 projects. 1 is Windows Application and the other is Class Library. In the class library, there's a class that the value of its datatype is needed by the Windows Application. I came up with this,

```
//Proj2
public class class1
{
    bool data1;  //supossed to be true but false in default
    public void method()
    {
        if (condition)
            data1 = true;
    }
 }

//Proj1
public class class2
{
    bool data2; //must be equal to data1

    public void method()
    {
        Proj2.Class1 class1 = new Proj2.Class1();
        data2 = class1.data1
        if (data2 == true)
            MessageBox.Show(data2.ToString());
    }
}
```

The Problem is, The output is always showing False instead of true. I'm sure 100% that the condition returns TRUE because  I tested it. I think the problem is the new instance, the datatype is reset to default which is false. So how do i get the original value. Note: There are two projects. Thank you!

Comment: Please give *real* code - even if it's artificially simple - rather than this pseudo-code which doesn't really help us work out what's going on. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're missing the call to `proj1.class1.method` that would set `data1` to `true`

So it should be

```
public void method()
{
    Proj2.Class1 class1 = new Proj2.Class1();
    class1.method();
    data2 = class1.data1;
    if (data2 == true)
        MessageBox.Show(data2.ToString());
}
```

> I think the problem is the new instance

Now perhaps you don't want to call `class1.method()` every time Class2.method is called.  If this is true you'll probably want to look at implementing a [singleton](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx). Then it would just be

```
public void method()
{
    data2 = Proj2.Class1.Instance.data1;
    if (data2 == true)
        MessageBox.Show(data2.ToString());
}
```